# Expansion of the Model to take credit card verification code value is Null

Tags: magento

I am during the expansion and development of cash flow
There is a problem to obtain the information of the credit card form, but read less than a credit card verification number (CVN)

For example, class

```
class Xxx_Yzz_Model_Method_Zcc extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
{
    public function setParams ()
    {
        ....
        $ CcCid = $ this-> getInfoInstance () -> getCcCid ();
        ....
    }
}
```

I reference the Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cc of, inside the assignData override, but in vain

```
public function assignData ($ data)
{
    if (! ($ data instanceof Varien_Object)) {
        $ data = new Varien_Object ($ data);
    }
    $ info = $ this-> getInfoInstance ();
    $ info-> setCcType ($ data-> getCcType ())
        -> setCcOwner ($ data-> getCcOwner ())
        -> setCcLast4 (substr ($ data-> getCcNumber (), -4))
        -> setCcNumber ($ data-> getCcNumber ())
        -> setCcCid ($ data-> getCcCid ())
        -> setCcExpMonth ($ data-> getCcExpMonth ())
        -> setCcExpYear ($ data-> getCcExpYear ())
        -> setCcSsIssue ($ data-> getCcSsIssue ())
        -> setCcSsStartMonth ($ data-> getCcSsStartMonth ())
        -> setCcSsStartYear ($ data-> getCcSsStartYear ())
    ;
    return $ this;
}
```

In addition, I also made reference to the Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cc, prepareSave override, can only obtain a credit card number, but did not get verification code

```
public function prepareSave ()
{
    $ info = $ this-> getInfoInstance ();
    if ($ this-> _canSaveCc) {
        $ info-> setCcNumberEnc ($ info-> encrypt ($ info-> getCcNumber ()));
    }
    // $ info-> setCcCidEnc ($ info-> encrypt ($ info-> getCcCid ())); 
    // These three lines seems useless
    $ info-> setCcNumber (null) 
        // These three lines seems useless
        -> setCcCid (null); 
        // These three lines seem useless
    return $ this;
}
```

Hope you can help me, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to save the CVV code (verification code), the prepareSave() method should look like this:

```
public function prepareSave ()
{
    $info = $this->getInfoInstance();
    if ($this->_canSaveCc) {
        $info->setCcNumberEnc($info->encrypt($info->getCcNumber()));
    }

    // Uncommented this line
    $info->setCcCidEnc($info->encrypt($info->getCcCid()));

    $info->setCcNumber(null)->setCcCid(null); 

    return $this;
}
```

Unless this saving/retrieving functionality was also disabled elsewhere, that should make Magento save the CVV Code. I believe that line that was commented out was what used to set the CVV Code to be saved in the database.

You may have to edit a template file for the admin to also make it show on the order management page. I'm not positive though.

At some point Magento stopped storing CVV codes for a reason as it violates the terms of service with credit card companies. I don't recommended re-introducing this functionality, but there ya go. Let me know if that works (unless you already found the solution).

Comment: looks great, but I guess that you also need to create a cc_cid_enc column at sales_flat_order_payment table.